# trivial problem with antlr4: text==null and no idea why

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have a grammar which worked already and i reactivated.
Now it does not work any more.
The point is two rules

```
parseRule 
@init {
   this.targets = new HashSet<Category>();
} // init 
    : (|->)? Name ( Trans '(' parseTargets ')' ) (->|)?
        {
            Category cat = new Category($Name.text);
            if ($Startup.text != null) {
                this.carGr.addStart(cat);
            }
            if ($Finish.text != null) {
                this.carGr.addStop(cat);
            }
            this.carGr.addRule(cat, targets);
        }
    ;
```

Very simple, neglecting the optional parts, i just parse a name and targets as follows:

```
parseTargets : (Name parseTargets?)
        {System.out.println("targets: "+targets);
    System.out.println("name: "+$Name.text);
    if ($Name.text != null){
    this.targets.add(new Category($Name.text));}};
```

I think, in each instance parsed, Name must be present and thus: $Name.text!=null.
So I dont need the if.
The truth is different.
Who can explain me???

Comment: Is this an Antlr4 grammar? You tagged this `Antlr4`, but `->` in `(|->)?` implies that you are using syntactic predicates, which not supported in Antlr4. The only other way `->` is allowed in Antlr4 is in lexerCommands.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the `(|->)?` is incorrect. It probably is a remnant of a v3 grammar: remove them. Also, there are references to non-existing `Startup` and `Finish` rule. The following will correctly print the contents of the `Name` rule to your console:

```
parseRule
 : Name Trans '(' parseTargets ')'
   {
     System.out.println($Name.text);
   }
 ;
```